# How can I override complete or full js file in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise

I want to override full js file instead of `js components` or `widgets`
When I try to place the file in my custom theme with the appropriate  path, still it's getting deployed from vendor not from override one.

I want it to be deploy from my custom theme, 
`app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable.js`

After `setup:static-content:deploy` it's still creating from vendor

`pub/static/frontend/Custom/Theme/en_US/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable.js` this is generated from `vendor`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should place it in
`app/design/frontend/Custom/Theme/Magento_ConfigurableProduct/web/js/configurable.js` 
you are missing the `web` folder in the path.

Then you should clear your `pub/static` folder and run
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`